# Get PHP Fatal error on globalized $wpdb: Call to a member function insert() on a non-object- I have no clue. What to do?

Tags: errors, php, debug

I am trying to utilize this function.  I cannot figure out why I am still getting the PHP error.  All I can figure out is that for some reason the template isn't able to access $wpdb.  I don't know what line needs to be placed in the functions.php (in theme folder) file that contains this function.  Please help me!!

```
function submitWeightUpdate( $userid, $weight ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $result = $wpdb->insert( 'wp_weights', array( 'user_id' => $userid, 'current_weight' => $weight ), array( '%d', '%d' ) );

    if (empty($_POST['weight'])) {
        $return['error'] = true;
        $return['msg'] = 'You did not enter a weight.';
    }
    else {
        $return['error'] = false;
        $return['msg'] = 'You\'ve entered: ' . $weight . ' as your new weight.';
    }

    echo json_encode($return);
}
```

I also tried setting the theme to the default one and it still won't work, so I have no idea what could be wrong with it!

Comment: Please try this `var_dump( isset( $wpdb ) );` in function and tell what it outputs.

Comment: Sorry I didn't reply earlier I didn't see your answer.  I tried it without globalizing $wpdb, globalizing via " $GLOBALS['wpdb'] = $wpdb;", and globalizing via "global $wpdb".  The result was always the same: bool(false).  Could it be a permissions issue or something?  In order to make the theme files editable inside of WP I had to set them chmod 767, wonder if I need to "reset" the permissions somehow or do some more modifications?

Comment: Hmmm... I am not quite sure why would `$wpdb` be uninitialized in this function, I assume rest of the site is working normally? How exactly you are running this code? In which template/whatever?

Comment: @Rarst: Those globals are unset mostly for two reasons: A) not yet initialized -or- B) because the object in there has been already destroyed (shutdown). And sure there is C) that someone just NULed/unset it which, well, can happen.

Comment: @hakre yeah, I understand technical reasons why it would be unset, I don't get why would it be that way in one specific function if rest of stuff works fine. I suspect this is more of loading some file directly or AJAX stuff.

Comment: @Rarst - I bet he is doing an AJAX load totally unrelated to WP ;) - Probably just copied over the $wpdb line because he wanted to extend his function with some database access. It's the first API function in that function, so every other might have been failed as well.

Comment: Ok that must be it, I am using ajax.  Can I not use AJAX?  If I am able to, what do I need to do to make it work?  The function is in the themes function.php file.  I wasn't sure the best way to call the function without using ajax, since I need to pass the text from my editbox as a variable.

Comment: @Brandon still not sure about your specifics, but definitely see [Ajax in Plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) in Codex.

Answer (score 3):

You did everything right with the globalize, the error message is just telling you that you called a function on $wpdb which does not exists.

Just check prior you do that $wpdb contains the object you're intersted in:

```
if (is_object($wpdb) && is_a($wpdb, 'wpdb')) {
    $result = $wpdb->insert( 'wp_weights', array( 'user_id' => $userid, 'current_weight' => $weight ), array( '%d', '%d' ) );
}
```

Alternatively you can add this below the global line to learn more:

```
global $wpdb;
var_dump($wpdb); // dump variable type and contents.
```

Additionally try:

```
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-load.php' );
global $wpdb;
```

You might not have wordpress ready to provide what you need in $wpdb.

Comment: In the conversation above the 2 guys figured out that I was using ajax and that was the root of the problem...now I just have to figure out how to properly either use ajax or rewrite my code to be able to pass text from my editbox...

Comment: Using AJAX is not the root of your problem. As using globals wasn't either.

Comment: Ok, so your code will probably help.  When I use require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-load.php' ); I get an error about loading ABSPATHwp-load.php but when I change it to ../../../wp-load.php then I get an error saying /httpdocs/wp-content/themes/smartone/wp-admin doesn't exist.  I assume wp-load is trying to load files based on the current directory which isn't working right.  How do I make it load properly?

Comment: wp-load.php does only do what's coded inside of it. Just open the file with your editor, read the source-code in there and you will learn all you need to know.

Comment: The exact error is "Failed opening required 'ABSPATHwp-load.php' (include_path='.:')"

Comment: I understand that it is looking for wp-admin because that is what is in the source code, but I don't want to mess up the stock code.  I assume I just need to run that require line in such a way that makes it run as if the current directory was ABSPATH, but don't know how.

Comment: "stock code"?, what does that mean? ABSPATH is a constant, and I use require to ensure that once it fails, it ends. -- ABSPATH is a constant normally available to the root of your worpdress isntallation. Please paste the _full_ OS path of the script you have problems with _and_ then the full OS path to the directory where you installed wordpress to.

Comment: By stock code I mean the code originally placed there by the creators of WP.  The OS path to the script file is '/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/subdomains/mysubdomain/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/smartone/functions.php' and wordpress is installed in '/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/subdomains/mysubdomain/httpdocs/'

Comment: Can you share as the HTTP URL (request url) when this fails? That should help to fit the pieces together.

Comment: I think this is what you wanted: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: wpdb in /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/subdomains/mysubdomain/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/smartone/functions.php on line 942, referer: http://mysubdomain.mydomain.com/?page_id=10

Comment: @Brandon - Hmm, that's not an AJAX request at all. You should get some wordpress support and go through with him on your server.

Comment: I agree, I just needed a slap upside the head and someone to tell me go RTFM!!!!  I got it fixed and working great after I read every plugin/ajax related doc page in the support section.  Thank you so much for all your hard work helping me!  That goes for everyone who tried to help me with this problem!

Comment: Have I missed something or have you not posted your eventual solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that $wpdb has been globalized when it hits your particular function. Try checking $GLOBALS and if it there is an entry for $wpdb remove the line $global $wpdb; at the start of your funciton.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I searched the themes functions.php file for "GLOBALS" and this is the only thing I came up with, I included the line above it to you could get an idea where it was located:  
function smartone_comment( $comment, $args, $depth ) {
 $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;

I got the idea to try declaring it that way though when you said that so I changed "global $wpdb" to "$GLOBALS['wpdb'] = $wpdb;" and I now get "PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: wpdb" as well as the original error.

Comment: So, if you do a print_r of GLOBALS at the start of your function -- what is the output?

Comment: Ok I did it, I have uploaded the results to [link](http://www.bcipg.com/globals.txt).  If I have the "$GLOBALS['wpdb'] = $wpdb;" line uncommented it adds "[wpdb] => " at the bottom of the list I uploaded.

Comment: @Brandon - Your output shows that `global $wpdb` is unset. Just in case you have not yet realized. There is no 'wpdb' entry [in the print_r $GLOBALS output](https://gist.github.com/826319) you posted.

Comment: I know, if I add the "global $wpdb;" line it adds "[wpdb] => " at the bottom of the list I uploaded.

Answer (score -1):

I faced this frustrating problem. None of the core functions were working.

So I included this:

```
require( '../../../wp-load.php' );
```

As a better practice:

```
if(!defined(ABSPATH)){
    $parse_uri = explode( 'wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] );
    var_dump($parse_uri);
    $parse_uri = str_ireplace('index.php', 'wp-load.php', $parse_uri);
    require_once( $parse_uri[0]);
}
```

Comment: Please explain in what context you need this. This is (a) in 99% of all cases unnecessary and (b) error prone as all relative path mappings with `..` dir changes are.

Comment: I needed this because wordpress core functions weren't loaded properly in the file I needed. None.

Comment: There were some suggestions of including it with ABSPATH also. Guess that's a better practice?

Comment: Yes, there are: Simply register your code as plugin, as mu-plugin or as theme. Without knowing the context I can't offer more than just this very general suggestion.

Comment: @kaiser: Finally used the code as stated in the edit above.

Comment: You know what? Take this code in your answer and add some detail to it (why you need that code) and ask a new question like "is it bad practice to reference wp-load.php?" or "do I need to include wp-load.php here?". You will get some pretty good answers on that and learn something along the way. Plus: You will be able to fix this answer and get some upvotes here as well :)